# Probability density function for the max value of independent variables

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

[image: how does this work]

I need help understanding the last part of this equation. I understand that all the variables are independent so you can multiply all of the probabilities but I'm not sure where the n comes from in the power of the answer . I'm sure the answer is very basic but for some reason I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

$F_X(x)$ is the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of $X$. Also, it is not stated here, but usually when independence is assumed, [identical distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) are also assumed. Therefore:

$$
P(X_1 \leq x_1) = P(X_2 \leq x_2) = \cdots =P(X_n \leq x_n) = P(X \leq x) = F_X(x)
$$

And:

$$
\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \leq x_i) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(X \leq x) = P(X \leq x)^n = F_X(x)^n
$$

Comment: Thanks, but how do we know that P(X1≤x1)=P(X2≤x2)

Comment: also I know this might be a silly question but why aren't all of the probabilities 1 as it is saying that x is the highest possible random variable in the sample so wouldn't the value always be lower than it?

Comment: It is stated in your question that $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ are independent. However, it is not stated that these random variables are identically distributed. Nevertheless, when random variables are assumed to be independent, it is also usually assumed that they are identically distributed, hence $P(X_1 \leq x_1) = P(X_2 \leq x_2)$. As for your second question, you did not mention in your original question any "sample", so I can only respond if you edit your question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

The product means to multiply all the terms from $i=1,...,n$.
Since the terms are all the same, multiplying $n$ of them together is the same as one of the terms raised to the $n^{th}$ power.